# Difference between んい and に

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, spelling, pitch-accent

I noticed that the word 単位 is written as た**んい** in hiragana, not た**に**. Is there a difference in the way んい and に are pronounced? If so, does the same principle go for んあ and な, んえ and ね, etc.?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. One way about thinking about it is syllabification: たんい is /tan.i/, たに is /ta.ni/. Try listening to some sound clips.

Comment: More minimal pairs for each vowel: 単位【たんい】 vs. 谷【たに】/​/ 品位【ひんい】 vs. 日【ひ】に /​/ 噴煙【ふんえん】 vs. 不燃【ふねん】 /​/ 犬【いぬ】 vs.　陰雨【いんう】 /​/ 指南【しなん】 vs. 新案【しんあん】 /​/ 無難【ぶなん】 vs. 文案【ぶんあん】 /​/ カノン【canon】　vs. 漢音【かんおん】

Comment: @blutorange and one of them can be extended to a minimal triple: カノン vs. 漢音 vs. 観音

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three differences

- **rhythm**
  たんい has three morae ("syllables"), where as たに has only two.
- **sound**
  たんい has a [uvular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_nasal) ("nasal") /ɴ/, i.e. [ta.ɴ.i], whereas たに has a "normal" /n/, i.e. [ta.ni].
- **pitch**
  たんい【HLL】 drops in pitch after the first mora, [たに​]【LHL】 drops in pitch after the second mora.

Try to listen for all three differences, they're all important.

---

The sound and rhythm of んあ んう んえ んお are analogous. (Pitch, of course, depends on the word.)

However, in some cases (e.g. 反応 はんのう from はんおう or 天皇 or 銀杏), the "nasalization" has been lost "officially", so to speak. But /i/ following /ɴ/ it is usually preserved, 雰囲気 ふんいき, 原因 げんいん, 単位 たんい etc. That said, no one likes the combination /ɴ.i/, so these words are often subject to [metathesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_%28linguistics%29), see for example [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3293/1628).

Comment: I have occasionally heard 雰囲気【ふんいき】 pronounced as ふいんき, exhibiting a kind of [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)).  (And then I clicked your "this answer" link and saw that very example. :) )

Answer (score 1):

単{たん} is pronounced たん and 位{い} is pronounced い.

Together, they are pronounced たんい or *tan'i*. This is distinctly different from に or *ni*.

For example, 谷{たに} is pronounced たに or *tani*. I don't know phonetic symbols so I apologize but you can sound these two out to hear how they are different.